# "The System Cannot Find File Specified" when trying to save postscript file as a image with PIL Module in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a program with a tkinter canvas that updates every so often with a new grid of colored squares. Every time it does so I am trying to save the canvas as an image. I can successfully create an .eps file using the "postscript" method. However, when trying to save and image using Image.save, I am receiving the error: 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'. I have included my code below.

```
fileName = "file"
map1.postscript(file=fileName+".eps", colormode='color')
img = Image.open("file.eps")
img.save("photo", format=".png")
```

Complete Error:

File "program.py", line 247, in 
Update()

File "program.py", line 227, in Update
img.save("photo", format=".png")

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2206, in save

```
self._ensure_mutable()
```

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 624, in _ensure_mutable
self._copy()

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 617, in _copy
self.load()

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 334, in load
self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale, transparency)

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 145, in Ghostscript

```
subprocess.check_call(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 359, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Are you sure the error happens on the `save()` call, and not before that?  Please post the entire error traceback message.

Comment: @Passerby that was an error copying the code over

Comment: @JohnGordon While running the debugger, the line that crashes is the save() call. I will add in the entire error

Comment: The hint lookup should fail as it doesn't expect `.` on the front, you would need to use `format="png"`. This would generate a file named `photo` not `photo.png`. You can simply write `img.save("photo.png")` and the correct format will be deduced anyway.

Comment: The ability of PIL/Pillow to convert an .eps file is not built-in - you have to install a separate utility called Ghostscript.  The error occurs on the save instead of the load, because the library doesn't actually load the image from disk until its data is actually needed, and it's only then that the lack of Ghostscript is noticed.